# passing a private void function inside another void function (compile error java)

Tags: java, compilation, void

Let's say I have a function which makes the names into first letter uppercase and the rest in lowercase when a parameter is entered.

I have another function to system print other things including the function I mentioned above.  But I keep on getting compile error saying 'void' type not allowed here.

Still really new with Java, not sure how I can adjust it.  Can someone give me a hand?

**This is the first function I mentioned**

```
private void makePrettyString(String modelName)
    {

        // Change first letter of the name into upper case and store the first char only
        char first = Character.toUpperCase(modelName.charAt(0));

        // lower case the whole name
        String lower = modelName.toLowerCase();

        // store the whole name except the first char into the variable
        String restInLowerCase = lower.substring(1);

        // Combine the first char (which is upper case) and the rest of the name (which is in lower case)
        this.modelName = first+restInLowerCase; 
    }
```

The second function to get some details

```
public void getCarDetails()
{
    System.out.println(makePrettyString(modelName));
}
```

Comment: your println call will print the result your makePrettyString method returns, but it doesn't return anything. make that makePrettyString method return a String.

Comment: omg! I figured I must be so over looking! I used `String makePrettyString` instead of void and the compile passes

Comment: Your first function needs to return something.

Comment: Exactly.. `println()` needs something to print but your `makePrettyString` is not returning (void) anything to print :)

Comment: let me try that again before I think I tried return and gave me error too must be trying too much I am all confused

Comment: @Dora - Make your first function return a *string*

Comment: change void of first method to string. it has to return a string so change the method signature to string .

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the help!
I just realized this is all I need to do change the method from `void` to `String` and of course as everyone says return something
So this works

```
private String makePrettyString(String modelName)
{

    // Change first letter of the name into upper case and store the first char only
    char first = Character.toUpperCase(modelName.charAt(0));

    // lower case the whole name
    String lower = modelName.toLowerCase();

    // store the whole name except the first char into the variable
    String restInLowerCase = lower.substring(1);

    // Combine the first char (which is upper case) and the rest of the name (which is in lower case)
    return = first+restInLowerCase; 
}
```

Comment: `return = ` is an illegal expression. You probably didn't mean to type that.

Comment: oops you are right, I meant `return this.modelName = first + restInLowerCase`

Answer (score 1):

Modify the function as:

```
private String makePrettyString(String modelName) {

   //Your existing code

   return this.modelName;
}
```

With the above your job gets resolved as the udner the System.out.println(fun-call) the argument is expecting some value as written which unfortunately is nothing but void!!

Answer (score 1):

change void of first method to string. it has to return a string so change the method signature to string

like this :

```
private String makePrettyString(String modelName)     // <-- change has to be made here  (String instead of void)
{

    // Change first letter of the name into upper case and store the first char only
    char first = Character.toUpperCase(modelName.charAt(0));

    // lower case the whole name
    String lower = modelName.toLowerCase();

    // store the whole name except the first char into the variable
    String restInLowerCase = lower.substring(1);

    // Combine the first char (which is upper case) and the rest of the name (which is in lower case)
    return = first+restInLowerCase; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line --> `System.out.println(makePrettyString(modelName));` will cause the error because the class `PrintStream` in which `println()` is defined doesn't have an overloaded method of `println()` which takes `void` as argument.

Check all overloaded methods [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html).

Just to clear the mist note that you cannot have a method that accepts `void` as argument in Java. Now, there is a *place holder / wrapper* for `void` which goes by the name `Void` which *also needs an argument of type `Void` .

Comment: please imporive your answer. One can think, tha it's possible to declare a method argument of type `void` in Java.

Comment: well it's not possible with `void` but yes with a `Void` with capital V, but still LostMind's answer is a bit misleading :)

Comment: @AlexeyGromov - edted it.

Comment: @Arkantos - Even with `Void`, it is NOT possible :).. You will still have to call the method like this : `methodThatCanTakeVoid(Void.TYPE.newInstance());` .

Comment: @TheLostMind.. I mean to say that `Void` can be used as a return type, I'm not saying doing that will fix the issue :)

Comment: @Arkantos - `methodThatCanTakeVoid(methodReturningVoid());` is still invalid. `Void` as a return type / argument is quite useless (to application developers).. and is used in few places.

Comment: @TheLostMind - Agreed. Like you said it's used in few places and is not used quite often but there are certain places where we need that as a workaround. Let's not go off topic from here. We both know where to use and where not to :)

Answer (score 0):

If both methods `getCarDetails()`  and `makePrettyString()` are in the same class,

Simply write
`makePrettyString();
System.out.println(this.modelName)`;

Instead of using a parameter `makePrettyString(String modelName)`, you can access `this.modelName` in the `makePrettyString()` method.

HTH.